# How to execute a chunk of code on a specific date in a .bat file?

Tags: date, batch-file, if-statement, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking to have a .bat file run at startup to check if the date it September 18th, which is my birthday. What I have written is 
`@echo off
if %date% == Sun 09/18/2016 start /d C:\Users\david\Documents\birthday.bat
end if`
but that doesn't work. I'm fairly new to scripting, so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I also tried using Schtasks to create a scheduled task that executes birthday.bat on the given date, but that failed entirely to create a task. I am running Win10 and want to do this entirely from a .bat file.

Comment: When debugging your batch scripts, get rid of (comment out) the `@echo off`.  Then, when you run it, you'll likely see where it's failing.

Comment: @WesLarson I tried making a test .bat file with the following code `if %date% == Thu 02/18/2016 echo "Hello world!"` but that still didn't print to cmd. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if "%date%" == "Thu 02/18/2016"

Comment: It should have given you an error `02/18/2016 was unexpected at this time.`.  This should indicate to you that the `if` command compared `%date% == Thu ` and then didn't understand the text that followed.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is "" around the dates in the `if` command.

remove the `/d` and I just add the "" after start and  " around the batch path.

So should look like this:

```
@echo off
if "%date%" == "Sun 09/18/2016" start "" "C:\Users\david\Documents\birthday.bat"
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

What went wrong when you used scheduled tasks, fixing that would be a better option than hitting the batch file each startup

Comment: When I attempted to have the .bat file create a scheduled task, I received no errors, but the task wasn't created. I messed around with the command for ~20 minutes.

Comment: Why is the batch file creating a scheduled task? You craft the task to RUN the batch file on a given date each year

Comment: I want this all to be executed from a batch file, say the code would look like this.
`Schtasks /create /TN "Birthday" /TR "C:\Users\david\Documents\birthday.bat" /SD 18/09/2016

@echo @echo "Happy Birthday, David!"> birthday.bat
@echo Start "" www.falconthirdborn.wix.com/lynxbirthday >> birthday.bat`